# How can I know the fragment transaction is finished?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmenttransaction

I want to make two fragment transactions in a row.

```
Fragment1 fragment1 = new Fragment1();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment1);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();

Fragment2 fragment2 = new Fragment2();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment2);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

However, if I do so, there will be some concurrence problem.
Is there a way for me to implement a callback function so that I can start the second transaction right after the first one is finished?

Comment: `there will be some concurrence problem` -- there certainly shouldn't be. The transactions should occur in the same order in which you commit them.

Answer (score 2):

You can manually flush the queue causing the pending fragment transaction to be executed. The call you're looking for is:

```
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

    ft.replace(android.R.id.content, fragment, name).addToBackStack(null).commit();
    fm.executePendingTransactions();
```

By calling the `fm.executePendingTransactions();` you force all pending actions to occur before continuing.